# JSDoc 3 fails with unclear message

Tags: jsdoc3

I'm using `JSdoc 3.3.3` to generate documentation.
I got the below error message:

```
Generating output files...org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: SyntaxError: Unterminated parenthetical (<eval'ed string>#1(Function)#201(Function)#53(Function)#17)
```

I have no clue of where to start looking for that is causing this. I need help to understanding the error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
* Changes the caption (title) of the window or a widget.
*
* @param (XsString|XsChar|String|string}
*            widgetName - The name of the widget.
* @param {XsString|XsChar|String|string}
*            caption - The new caption.
*/
```

The problem is start parenthesis. That should be a curly bracket at the first @param.